# React Application Gives 404 error on production when l click download, but its working fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The application is using nodejs at the backend. Nodejs is deployed on a Cpanel using VPS and it's working fine but the react app deployed on netlify connected to it is returning: POST https://thirsty-thompson-1a4ddf.netlify.app/create-pdf 404 in the console when l click the download button.

**Link to the application is below**:

https://thirsty-thompson-1a4ddf.netlify.app/

**Error being shown**
[image]

**Running application with the error shown on console**
[image]

The function to download in the react app is:

```js
createAndDownloadPdf = () => {
    axios.post('/create-pdf', this.state.testeeRecords)
      .then(() => axios.get('fetch-pdf', { responseType: 'blob' }))
      .then((res) => {
        const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

        
        saveAs(pdfBlob, "fileName.pdf" );
      })
  }
```

index.js with nodejs code. Thats the code to post data to the pdf to download.

```js
app.post('/create-pdf',  (req, res) => {

    pdf.create(pdfTemplate(req.body), {}).toFile('result.pdf', (err) => { //passing getByOne json
        if(err) {
            res.send(Promise.reject());
        }

        res.send(Promise.resolve());
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your backend is running? Is it possible netlify only serves your frontend? Because everything else seems fine.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, only the front-end is on netlify. if l connect the deployed backend with the reactjs app which is running on the localhost there are no errors, so that's why l think the backend is working fine unless there is something I'm missing. Also the backend is returning the required JSON data at: https://reportgeneration.bradfields.co.zw/items

Comment: Ok so thats your problem. app.post('/create-pdf' tells it to go to the same host the page is served on, but your backend is on another host. You can try to do app.post('https://yourbackend.com/create-pdf', but then you'll have a cors problem you'll have to solve. https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Comment: Ok thanks let me try to do that

Comment: I have changed the post code on the server to: app.post('https://reportgeneration.bradfields.co.zw/create-pdf',  (req, res) => { , .....and had already enabled CORS but still getting :   POST https://epz-report-generation.netlify.app/create-pdf 404

Comment: My bad. You need to change the axios.post not the app.post. Sorry

Comment: oops l got an error: GET https://vibrant-bartik-67f581.netlify.app/fetch-pdf 404. Maybe for you to get a full view of the application here is the github link. most of the code is in app.js and index.js

Comment: Eureka it worked. l also changed the axios.get to axios.get('https://reportgeneration.bradfields.co.zw/fetch-pdf', that is l also added the backend link on that line of code. Thanks mate.